# Firefox becomes default browser after upgrade. Cannot revert to Google Chrome

Tags: 11.04, firefox, google-chrome, default-browser

Upgraded my notebook to Natty Beta 1 two days ago. All seems to be in order except for a very annoying little thing. I used to have Google Chrome as my default browser, and after the upgrade, this default was changed to Firefox. Note that when I go to the Google Chrome settings and to the Firefox setting it seems that Google Chrome is set as my default browser, but whenever I click on a URL from outside a browser it's Firefox that comes up and not Chrome.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that there is this little application called "Preferred Applications" and you can set your default browser there. I figured this out, 2 minutes after posting my question. Well, three things are a mystery to me:

1. Why was my default changed?
2. How is a "new" user supposed to know about this "Preferred Applications" utility? This utility is not in the launcher, and I only recalled it by sheer luck.
3. Why are the settings within Firefox and within Google Chrome not working?

Comment: You're probably experiencing this bug report (upgrades usually don't mess with your preferred apps): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/670128

Comment: Power button > system settings opens up the control panel where the preferred application manager, and the other tools previously found in the "system" menu, are now located - that's how a "new" user is suppose to find it

Comment: If you have a new question please do not ask it in the body of an answer but either update your original question - or if the scope of your questions has changed from the original topic [Ask a new Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug report for this, because this may be a bug that is part of 11.04.  Again, 11.04 is in beta, so bugs are bound to happen.

Comment: EvilPhoenix, thanks! But I may simply just be an idiot... Turns out that there is this little application in Ubuntu called "Preferred Applications" and you can set your default browser there. I figured this out, 2 mins after posting my question.
Well, three things are a mystery to me:
1. Why was my default changed?
2. How is a "new" user supposed to know about this "Preferred Applications" utility?
3. Why are the settings within Firefox and within Google Chrome not working?

Comment: Again, Natty is in **beta**.  The malfunctions like this are called **bugs**.  The settings within Firefox and Chrome may not be applying, possibly due to a **bug** in Natty.  As such, you may consider filing a bug report anyways.  And Firefox and Chrome are supposed to apply settings anyways, so the lack of that working definitely points to some type of bug.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in chrome such to check to see if it is the default browser it is easy to change from there.

**Edited**
The button to set chrome as the system default browser is in the preferences menu or chrome.

Comment: There is a bug/feature in Ubuntu 11.04 that prevents/overrides that button from doing anything at all. The way to solve this problem is to go to the "Preferred Applications" and select chrome from there.