# Cannot make Google Chrome Default browser

Tags: 11.04, google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox becomes default browser after upgrade. Cannot revert to Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33378/firefox-becomes-default-browser-after-upgrade-cannot-revert-to-google-chrome)

I installed Chromium. It worked well. But I could not set it as default. It was there in my Dash, but every time I opened it, it asked me whether I want to set it as default. I even tried changing it in the Preferences. I could click on Make it my default browser but it didn't make a change.

So I installed Chrome Beta. It worked well initially. Following a last update (12.0.742.30 beta) this problem has started again.

Is this is a bug? or is it just me? and how can I make Chrome remember my preference?

(P.S. I don't want to switch to the stable channel.)

[Update: I found a workaround that I select 'do not ask me again' when it asks me  for my preference. This stops the annoying messages, and since Chrome is the only browser on my Natty currently it is default in any case. But this restricts me from installing any other browser.]

Answer (score 1):

You can change "Preferred Applications" under System \ Preferences \ Preferred Applications
(Classic Gnome) in Unity push the on\off button and go through the settings to Preferred Applications.